# Angular ng-include causing Angular to be called more than once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm getting this error in the console:

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

The reason the above is displaying is something to do with this block of code in my `view` called `home.html`:

```
<div ng-include="'testhtml.html'"></div>
```

The output on my application is that the index.html is being output again within my view. What is causing this?

This is my route:

```
  var main = {
        name: "MainPage",
        url: "/",
        title: 'My homepage',
        views: {
            "mainContent": {
                templateUrl: "modules/main/template/home.html",
                controller: "MainPageController"
            },
            "sidebar":{
                templateUrl: "modules/main/template/sidebar.html",
                controller: "SidebarController"
            }
        }
    };
```

Gulp file

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src([
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular/angular.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-tour/dist/angular-tour-tpls.min.js'
    ])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIRDEST + 'lib/'));

    gulp.src([DIRSOURCE + 'modules/module.js', DIRSOURCE + 'modules/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIRDEST + 'modules'));
});
```

Comment: The jQuery library is included before or after Angular library ?

Comment: It is included before angular library I've added my libraries above. I'm using `gulp` to manage them

Comment: Try to put Angular before jQuery

Comment: Tried that there it just breaks application

Comment: `testhtml.html` probably has a script reference to angular. It only needs to be in the main html file.